# How can I locate a rim joist in a two-story brick house?

Tags: roof, patio

**Second floor Rim board location**

I need to know how to spot it to install the ledger using  [BVLZ from Simpson Strong-Tie](https://www.strongtie.com/decks_decksandfences/bvl_plate/p/bvlz). My house, second story, floor rim board is behind the brick wall I was told, but no way to see anything.

I am planning a shed patio roof with an 8' span.

Comment: FYI, a lean-to is a panel resting on the ground (as the name implies). You probably have a "shed roof" in mind--a simple, single-plane structure.

Answer (score 2):

The rim joist will normally be immediately below the subfloor. Therefore, transfer your floor location to the outside through a window or door, and lower the mark the equivalent of the subfloor and finish floor thicknesses. You can often find that in a floor vent or similar penetration.

You haven't given us the where or when of your house, but the rim is likely to be a 9½" 2x10 if built before ~1990, and it could be an OSB plank of similar height or slightly taller after that *or* an engineered truss system about 18" high with top and bottom 2x4 bands (hollow between).

Comment: Would it be worth inspecting it through the ceiling of the first floor to avoid the chance of attaching to the middle of an engineered one?

Comment: Sure, if location and type can't be confirmed by other means. It's a rare home which doesn't offer _some_ opening through which to peer.

Comment: the house was built in 2003,Fox and Jacobs(the builder)in Dallas,Tx,thank you!!